# Increasing the width of C 's print Screen?

Tags: c

The screen on which our output appears in C is 8 tab spaces wide. Is there any hack to increase the width of C 's print screen ? In case it is necessary, I am working in windows on codeblocks IDE .

Comment: The definition of a *tab space* is not universal. The width of an output terminal is not universal. As far as the C language is concerned, until you print a newline character, all output will be written on the first line, no matter how wide it gets.

Comment: Make the window bigger. For the reasons Arjun said. Additionaly you could just make the font smaller.

Comment: A printf function in my main function has over 200 characters and it gets wrapped to 2nd, 3rd, 4th lines (and I never added a '\n').

Comment: @NikunjBanka - Like I said: That is not something you can fix from the program. Its the terminal's problem. C handed a nice 200 character line to the terminal, and the terminal *chose* to wrap it. In this case, its the problem of the Windows terminal (I don't know much about Windows, but I guess you need to fiddle with [something along these lines](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Settings#Q:_How_do_I_change_the_default_location_of_the_output_terminal.3F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C programming language and libraries don't have a print screen per se.  They send output to streams.  In the case of the `printf` function, for example, there is a default output stream called stdout, which echoes to your terminal, so the following two calls are equivalent:

```
 printf( "hi!\n" );
 fprintf( stdout, "hi!\n" );
```

A line of output to a stream is delimited by a newline character (`\n`).  (But since you're on windows, you may need to end your lines with `\r\n`, especially if you redirect your output to a text file sometimes.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).)

So I think your question is really about how to control the number of characters your terminal will print before automatically wrapping to the next line (or truncating).  (And maybe how your terminal will deal with tabs?)  This will depend on what hardware, os, and shell you are running, but [Termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) is probably where you want to start if you're using a unix style shell.  If you're using a windows `CMD.EXE` window, there are some settings you can access through the "Layout" tab of the "Properties menu", which is accessible via the window menu icon in the upper left hand corner of the menu bar; this will let you set your screen buffer width and thus control whether long lines will wrap or result in a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: \r\r\n? Where did that come from? Windows end of line is always \r\n.

Comment: @SecurityMatt -- some formatted text controls use the double carriage return.  It's hideous!

Comment: (Or maybe I'm having a VB flashback?)

Comment: I think so. \r\n is the Windows newline character. I've never seen \r\r\n before.